# Return after login going through contribution flow doens't bring up contribution page

Tags: joomla, contribution-page

Going through contribution flow reach point where user needs to log in

> If you would like to create an account on this site, check the box
>   below and enter a Username and a password. If you already have an
>   account please login before completing this form.
>
> Please login is a link that takes one to login and then return to
>   contribution page.

Problem is after logging in  the url is

`https://www.isfpta.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&amp;task=civicrm/contribute/transact&amp;Itemid=1726&amp;reset=1&amp;id=13`

If you pull the amp: out after the & it works.
Current versions of Joomla 3.36 and civicrm 4.6.3

Comment: note that the url lists "& a m p : " without the spaces. and works when I pull out the amp:.

Answer (score 2):

This may well be a bug. It would be helpful if you could recreate it on [demo.civicrm.org](http://demo.civicrm.org). See https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting

Comment: The demo for joomla doesn't have menus turned on for me to add the contribution page to. not sure how to attach it to the joomla to run the test.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same behaviour/error occurs in Event Registration if user logs in and then is (not) redirected back.
See my question: [Redirect back to Event Registration after login fails](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3829/redirect-back-to-event-registration-after-login-fails)